# Enable "Trash" with Network Share over AFP

Tags: mac, file-sharing, afp

I have a OS X machine sharing an external drive (connected via firewire) to other Mac clients.  All are running Snow Leopard and the protocol being used is AFP, FYI.

When a user tries to delete a file from the shared folder from one of the clients, it deletes immediately and does not go through the OS X "Trash" system. Is there some way to configure the server or the clients such that the items go through the Trash system or is that just not possible?

In a general web search, I found lots of references to the Network Trash Folder, but all of the references seems to be very old (OS 9 and OS 10.0-10.1).  They also didn't indicate how to enable it.

Answer (score 1):

The network trash cans went away when AFP 3 came in. Local files still get sent to .Trashes but it is no longer possible to do anything but delete files immediately with network shares. You might rig up an Access Control List to prevent users from deleting files though.